# Call Swift function in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a problem to use a method developed in Swift that I want to use in objective C.

**Swift 4 Class:** in this function I retrieve the information of the user (like userNumber, secretCode)

```
@objc class MySwiftClass: HPTableViewController {
    func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)!) {
        //API get profile and Bearer token
        let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
        let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/profile")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //get information in token
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
                let sub = json["sub"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                if completion != nil{
                    completion(sub)
                }
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

for example at the end of the function I get

```
  sub["usernumber"]! // print +224625259239
  sub["secretcode"]! // print $2a$08$DIrq1iKnjkkY4KgI3Mqy7.aWC39m2aFMncfJSkom9l0yaXhGlH35m
```

**Objective-C implementation (Objective-C.m)** I want to display this information above

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
MySwiftClass* userProfil = [[MySwiftClass alloc]init];
[userProfil  loadMemberProfil: ^(NSDictionary *sub) { // No visible @interface for 'MySwiftClass' declares the selector 'loadMemberProfil:'
userNumber = sub[@"usernumber"];
secretCode = sub[@"secretcode"];
}];
```

but I get this error message  No visible @interface for 'MySwiftClass' declares the selector 'loadMemberProfil:' could someone help me? please :)

Comment: I think you want `[userProfil loadMemberProfileCompletion:...]`

Comment: Instead of `@objc`, `@use objcMembers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
@objcMembers class MySwiftClass: UIViewController { --- }
```

**OR**

```
@objc func loadMemberProfil(completion: ((_ sub : [String: AnyObject]) -> Void)!) { --- }
```

---

With this call

```
[userProfil loadMemberProfilWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary*dic ) {

}];
```

Comment: ThX it's Work :)